# Spring, JAX-WS publishing through current Context

Tags: java, spring, jax-ws

Spring provides a JAX-WS exporter class which creates a simple `httpserver` which is provided by jdk6. Is there a possibility to receive the current webserver context within spring and publish the WS through this context?

`SimpleHttpServerJaxWsServiceExporter` has a server property in best case I would like to define my server as ref and use this exporter which would fit all my needs.